# Question about equation solving and its solution

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find alpha which is the root of the following .

```
 eq1 = -(
  (2*V*(α^3 - θ*(4*θ + Sqrt[α*(α + 8*θ)]) + α^2*(10*θ + Sqrt[α*(α + 8*θ)]) + α*θ*(-1 + 12*θ + 6*Sqrt[α*(α + 8*θ)]))
  ) / (Sqrt[α*(α + 8*θ)]*(α + 2*θ + Sqrt[α*(α + 8*θ)])^2))
```

Thus, I use

```
Solve[eq1 == 0, α]
```

The output gives four values of alpha. Based on this result, I guess that eq1 is quartic because I have four roots. However, when I check exponent of eq1 using

```
 Exponent[eq1, α]
```

it gives 2 which means eq1 is quadratic with respect to alpha.
Does anybody know why this thing happen?
Is it possible to have a quadratic equation has four roots or is there any problem I don't realize?
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You are reasoning about it as it was a polynomial, which it is not, so I'm not sure what do you mean.

Comment: @Kuba my question is why eq1=0 has four roots?This basically means eq1=0 is quartic equation. However, the command exponent gives 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
eq1 = -((2*
       V*(α^3 - θ*(4*θ + 
            Sqrt[α*(α + 
                8*θ)]) + α^2*(10*θ + 
            Sqrt[α*(α + 8*θ)]) + α*θ*(-1 + 
            12*θ + 
            6*Sqrt[α*(α + 
                 8*θ)])))/(Sqrt[α*(α + 
           8*θ)]*(α + 2*θ + 
          Sqrt[α*(α + 8*θ)])^2));
```

"[`Exponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exponent.html)[expr, form] gives the maximum power with which form appears in the expanded form of expr." Unless `expr` is a polynomial (which `eq1` is not), `Exponent` says nothing about the number of roots of  `expr`.

```
Length@Solve[eq1 == 0, α]

(* 4 *)
```

For real roots there are either one or two roots depending on the region. See documentation for explanation of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects.

```
sol = Solve[eq1 == 0, α, Reals]

(* {{α -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-2 θ^2 + 12 θ^2 #1 + (θ - 18 θ^2) #1^2 + 
       6 θ #1^3 + #1^4 &, 
     1], -(1/8) < θ < 0 || θ < -(1/8)]}, {α -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-2 θ^2 + 12 θ^2 #1 + (θ - 18 θ^2) #1^2 + 
       6 θ #1^3 + #1^4 &, 2], θ > 0 || θ < -(1/8)]}} *)

Plot[Evaluate[α /. sol], {θ, -1, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 13, Bold] & /@ {θ, α}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[sol[[All, 1, -1, -1]], {0.7, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what  I want to find.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `Exponent` is a bit unclear about what it does when the expression isn't a polynomial. Let's tease apart the non-polynomial features of your problem.

```
Solve[Sqrt[x^2] - 1 == 0, x]
(* {{x -> -1}, {x -> 1}} *)
```

Two solutions, obviously correct. One might reasonably see this as a slightly disguised quadratic equation. However,

```
Exponent[Sqrt[x^2] - 1, x]
(* 1 *)
```

Also,

```
Solve[(x^2 - 1)/x == 0, x]
(* {{x -> -1}, {x -> 1}} *)
Exponent[(x^2 - 1)/x, x]
(* 1 *)
```

The documentation for `Exponent` refers to the "expanded form" without defining exactly what that means. I hypothesize that it uses `PowerExpand`, and takes the difference between the leading exponents of the numerator and denominator of the result. That fits the examples above, and others I've tried. Thus, `Exponent` does not predict the number of roots for a non-polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply